# How to unistall cinco dias from ubuntu phone

Tags: uninstall, phone

How can I uninstall cinco dias app? Is this possible?

Theres a couple of others I'd like to remove too but can't find those in the store searching via the name to uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you go the **Apps** scope and hold the corresponding icon pressed, it will open a new tab where you can uninstall or open it.